# How to rewrite this code from 'each' to 'for'?:

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

How to rewrite this code from 'each' to 'for':

```
myDiv.scroll(function () { 
    $nower = (($(this).scrollTop() + $start_pr) / $skorost) + $ugol * 8;
    $.each(ImgDiv, function(index) {
        $(this).offset({ top: Math.cos((index + 1) * $ugol + $nower) * $size_dug + $smes_y, left: Math.sin(-((index + 1) * $ugol + $nower)) * $size_dug + $smes_x });
    });
});
```

I'm trying, but it's doesn't work: =(

```
myDiv.scroll(function () {  
    var $nower = (($(this).scrollTop() + $start_pr) / $skorost) + $ugol * 8;
    for (var ink = 0, len = ImgDiv.length; ink < len; ink++) {
        ImgDiv[ink].offset({top: Math.cos((ink + 1) * $ugol + $nower) * $size_dug + $smes_y, left: Math.sin(-((ink + 1) * $ugol + $nower)) * $size_dug + $smes_x });
    };
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with `$.each`?

Comment: high-speed performance =)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to call `jQuery` function offset on `DOM` object instead of jQuery object. Convert `DOM` object to `jQuery` object as under.

Change

```
ImgDiv[ink]
```

To

```
$(ImgDiv[ink])
```

Your code would be

```
myDiv.scroll(function () {  
        var $nower=(($(this).scrollTop()+$start_pr)/$skorost)+$ugol*8;
        for (var ink=0, len = ImgDiv.length; ink < len; ink++)
        {
        $(ImgDiv[ink]).offset({top: Math.cos((ink+1)*$ugol+$nower)*$size_dug+$smes_y, left: Math.sin(-((ink+1)*$ugol+$nower))*$size_dug+$smes_x });
        };
    });
```